# AutoHotKey Script required to visit a secure page and click a link

Tags: autohotkey

I need to visit https://wmspanel.com/dashboard/publish_point_report after every hour this page is password protected lets say username = ktest and password = gora

once logged in you will see an [export](/dashboard/export_publish_point_report) this should be click to download a file.

Can somebody please make me this script.

Comment: Why can't you simply make the script yourself using the script recording tool that comes with Autohotkey?

Comment: different default browser and screen sizes? I will share this script with other people who will run this script on their workstations

Comment: Different browsers will be challenge unless you write methods for each browser.

Comment: @iglvzx you can use a combination of Alt+Something to select the URL bar, and tab/shift+tab keys to navigate the forms on the site.  Just ensure the window is in focus and it should be fine (you also have to check that the page has loaded - maybe ask the user?).

Answer (score 0):

I have used autohotkey extensively.  That said, if I wanted to do what you are describing, I wouldn't hesitate to use the built in macro recorder for iMacros.  The free version can be run off of any number of user's boxes. It works on Chrome, Mozilla and IE. You might have to edit the code slightly, but it has built in functions to click, download the file and autosave it a specified location.

One convenient trick I have used to schedule it is to bookmark the iMacros macro and just use autohotkey/taskscheduler to open up Mozilla and call it (simply by sending a keystroke to the Mozilla browser launching the 'bookmarked' iMacro).  As far as I know that trick only works on Mozilla however.